# Read file as a list of tuples of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, readfile

I want to read a text file using Python. My list must be like this:

```
    mylist = [((5., 10.), (6.4, 13)),
              ((7., 11.), (5.6, 5.)),
              ((4., 5.67), (3.1, 2.)),
              ((13., 99.), (3.2, 1.1))]
```

My text file is:

```
    text file: 5., 10., 6.4, 13.
               7., 11., 5.6, 5.
               4., 5.67, 3.1, 2.
               13., 99., 3.2, 1.1
```

python code is:

```
    with open('test.txt') as f:
      mylist = [tuple((tuple(map(float, i.split(','))))) for i in f]
    print(mylist)
```

My result:

```
    [(5.0, 10.0, 6.4, 13.0), (7.0, 11.0, 5.6, 5.0), (4.0, 5.67, 3.1, 2.0), (13.0, 99.0, 3.2, 1.1)]
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go one step further:

```
lst = [(5.0, 10.0, 6.4, 13.0), (7.0, 11.0, 5.6, 5.0), (4.0, 5.67, 3.1, 2.0), (13.0, 99.0, 3.2, 1.1)]
lst2 = [(tt[:2],tt[2:]) for tt in lst]

print(lst2)
```

Output

```
[((5.0, 10.0), (6.4, 13.0)), ((7.0, 11.0), (5.6, 5.0)), ((4.0, 5.67), (3.1, 2.0)), ((13.0, 99.0), (3.2, 1.1))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the lines into two separate tuples. Changing `mylist` to this will work:

```py
mylist = [tuple([tuple(s[:2]), tuple(s[2:])]) 
    for s in [list(map(float, i.split(",")))
    for i in f]]
```

Comment: I try it but there is a problem in my output:[(('5.', ' 10.'), (' 6.4', ' 13.\n')), (('7.', ' 11.'), (' 5.6', ' 5.\n')), (('4.', ' 5.67'), (' 3.1', ' 2.\n')), (('13.', ' 99.'), (' 3.2', ' 1.1'))]

Comment: This is incompatible with the output you posted earlier.  Please resolve the discrepancy.

Comment: whooops missed out float conversion - added that now

Comment: Thanks for your helping, but I do not know why this error occurred:    for s in [map(float, i.split(","))
TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable

Comment: ah, in python3 you need to wrap `map` with a `list` call as it returns an iterator - updated again

Comment: That is a good idea, thanks. Now my output is correct : [((5.0, 10.0), (6.4, 13.0)), ((7.0, 11.0), (5.6, 5.0)), ((4.0, 5.67), (3.1, 2.0)), ((13.0, 99.0), (3.2, 1.1))]